# Flatten a multidimensional array without recursion

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

This is the meal planner app I'm still working on. I've gotten a lot of useful help so far. You can see the view source at http://maureenmoore.com/momp_tests/122212.html

I am using the following in my process.php (which the jquery form gets submitted to)

```
$stack = array();

foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
{
    array_push($stack,$value);
}
$stack = array_values($stack);

print_r($stack);

$comma_separated = implode(",", $stack);

echo "\n\n" . $comma_separated . "\n\n";
```

When I click the submit button at localhost it shows an error for array to string conversion because it's a multidimensional array. How can I get rid of the first null key without resorting to a recursive function? I don't see the error any more now that I've uploaded it to my hosting account but it's not printing a comma-separated list because it's a multidimensional array with a key of null.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I got confused, let me know if i have understood it, right. 
You are getting an error because it is a multidimensional array.

Try this

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $tempArray) {
          foreach ($tempArray as $key => $value) {
            array_push($stack,$value);
          }
}
```

or

```
$tempArray = $_REQUEST;
foreach ($tempArray[0] as $key => $value) {
         array_push($stack,$value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter() to remove nulls

```
$new_array_without_nulls = array_filter($array_with_nulls, 'strlen');
```

And array_reduce() to convert to comma separated instead of implode
    http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: Why would you suggest using array_reduce instead of implode? Seems like that would only complicate the process.

Answer (score 0):

The data that you are sending to your php script is `{data: selectedBoxes}` and you are using the post method. And `selectBoxes` is an array containing the stuff that is dragged to the right-hand box.

To get your data in php, you just need to iterate over the `data` post variable:

```
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key => $value)
{
  // get all meals that were dragged
}
```

Also note, if you drag one of the things in the box around, you get multiple versions of the same meal.

Comment: @Maureen Moore You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you (the mark below the vote-count).